# Redirect Large Number of Web Sites from Azure to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, load-balancing, redirect

What is the best-practice method (considering cost, complexity and performance) to redirect a large number of websites to another server?  Each site's DNS contains an A record pointing to an old IP address which is being decommissioned.

For added detail, each site has a DNS A record that point to a.a.a.a, an IP address on Azure, and we would like to instead have those websites point to b.b.b.b, an IP address on AWS.

Is there a best-practice method to perform this redirection without needing to update the DNS of thousands of websites?

After doing some research:

- Because the IP address is owned by Microsoft (Azure), I likely cannot use AWS EC2 BYOIP.  Ref. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html
- Because there are thousands of websites each with their own DNS, updating the A record or adding a CNAME record would be very difficult and time consuming

It's possible to set up a load balancer on Azure which redirects to AWS, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

> Each site's DNS contains an A record pointing to an old IP address which is being decommissioned.

> Updating that A record or adding a CNAME record would be very difficult and time consuming

Yes. Indeed it would, ***if*** you indeed need to make all changes individually  and by hand.

- investigate if your current registrar and/or DNS provider offers a proper API (that will allow you to automate making DNS updates and reduce the amount of manual labour by a fair margin)

When they don't - you can make the effort now and avoid having such a herculean task in the future:

- reconcile that you will need to invest and do lots of manual effort now anyway and choose to spend that effort into something future proof that will avoid having to repeat that manual effort. Treat this as an opportunity to move all your current DNS records and/or domains to a DNS provider (or registrar) that does offers a proper API or decide to host your DNS in-house which will also allow you to more easily manipulate DNS records.

  - Migrate as-is first.
  - After DNS has migrated: automate doing the reconfigurations you need to make to decommission the old IP-address.
- reconcile that you will need to invest and do lots of manual reconfiguration now and create those CNAME records that will reduce the effort of changing IP-addresses in the future

Or live with the fact that decommissioning the IP will cost too much and offers too little benefit and reconsider. Sometimes decisions were made without knowledge of the all implications and their full impact and they can be appealed.

Setting up a load balancer / reverse proxy on the old IP-address is of course an option, but you're adding extra complexity and most likely you'll be paying at least twice  for all traffic (once for the traffic between the website visitor and your load balancer/reverse proxy and a second time for the traffic between the load balancer and your new webserver(s).